# Flutter - Overlaying a button with GridView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So i have the following view created with this code:

```
return Column(
        children:[
          Expanded(
            child: gridView()
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_box),
            iconSize: 30,
            onPressed: () {
              _showPicker();
            }
          )
        ]);
```

[image]

I would however like to have the IconButton not have that white background that is spread across the screen. How would I go on about making it to be like that and instead be overlayed with the GridView. Is the Column a wrong type of widget to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Stack:

```
return Stack(
alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
        children:[
          gridView(),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_box),
            iconSize: 30,
            onPressed: () {
              _showPicker();
            }
          )
        ]);
```